# Trying to understand an application of expectation-Maximization algorithm

Tags: bayesian, image-processing, expectation-maximization

In [this image downscaling paper](https://johanneskopf.de/publications/downscaling/paper/downscaling.pdf), the authors apply the Expectation-Maximization algorithm to solve an image downscaling problem. I've never done Bayesian statistics, so I find some parts a bit hard to understand. Here's the key part, the calculation of Gaussian kernels in the expectation stage.  I'm trying to understand how does one come up with the formulas f and g, highlighted in red and green, and what associated reading do I need to do to understand them further. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Digging through, it looks like the red area looks like squared Mahalanobis distance (multiplied by -0.5), but it's not mentioned at all in the paper...

Comment: Digging through a bit more, I found out that these functions represent multivariate and univariate probability density functions. But for some reason, the f/g functions don't include the scalars multiplied by the exponents